# how does Python do the type checking compared to Java?

Tags: java, python

Here's an example:
In Python, you can type: x = 1 or x = 'hello' without declaring the type for x, However, in Java, you cannot do this, you must declare the type of x firstly.

So my question is why Python allow this behavior, how does Python do the type checking compared to Java? (In my thought, In python, x just is a label, and it can point to anything. Can anyone give me some hints about the mechanism when x doing the assignment operation)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system

Comment: I also like this one: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language

Comment: You are correct, `x` is just a label.  What exactly do you want to know?  Are you asking about the internal implementation details?

Comment: i thins python affect a type to a variable when you give it a value .

in that example `a=10` the typeof  'a' is int the type affected automatically and dynamically .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not have static type checking like Java does. Instead Python uses dynamic typing along with the common methodologies of [duck-typing](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) and [it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp). However, you can manually check the type of an object by using [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) (which some consider inferior but I disagree):

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x.__class__
<type 'int'>
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
>>> isinstance(x, str)
False

>>> x = 'hello'
>>> x.__class__
<type 'str'>
>>> isinstance(x, int)
False
>>> isinstance(x, str)
True
```

See also:

- [Standard types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)
- [Execution model](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_type-checking_and_runtime_type_information) you have all the information you need, this is the part about dynamic typing(Python) and you have also information about how type system works. [Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language) is a nice and simple article about Python typing.